# Ransack accepting virtual attributes for belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

in my user.rb

```
ransacker :full_name do |parent|
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('concat_ws', [' ', parent.table[:first_name], parent.table[:last_name]])
end
```

which grabs the fields from User

```
 :first_name
 :last_name
```

and it works!

But I'm also trying to search users on Projects but I am unable to figure out how to use ransacker to accomplish that

I get a

```
 Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'projects.first_name
```

how do i get it to look up the users first_name and last_name instead of project

i've tried virtual attributes and it works in the console but i get a an unknown column when I try to use it with ransacker

Please help me Obi Wan your my only hope

Comment: See https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/166